# for loop calculation giving null after several loops

Tags: for-loop, null, dart, flutter

I want to make a graph from user inputs, when the user inputs the numbers and presses a button, the onpressed function goes into a for loop to calculate all the graph points. however right now the for loop is giving wrong values and after a certain amount of loops it starts giving null values here and there, not sure what is causing this.

here is my onPressed function:

```
onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                  for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                      value1 = 0.0;
                      print(i.toString() + ' , ' + j.toString());
                      if (j == 0) {
                        value1 = (_finalDrive *
                                (i * 10 * mphtokmph) *
                                _gear1 *
                                _coefficient) /
                            _tireDiameter;
                      } else if (j == 1) {
                        value1 = (_finalDrive *
                                (i * 10 * mphtokmph) *
                                _gear2 *
                                _coefficient) /
                            _tireDiameter;
                      } else if (j == 2) {
                        value1 = (_finalDrive *
                                (i * 10 * mphtokmph) *
                                _gear3 *
                                _coefficient) /
                            _tireDiameter;
                      } else if (j == 3) {
                        value1 = (_finalDrive *
                                (i * 10 * mphtokmph) *
                                _gear4 *
                                _coefficient) /
                            _tireDiameter;
                      } else if (j == 4) {
                        value1 = (_finalDrive *
                                (i * 10 * mphtokmph) *
                                _gear5 *
                                _coefficient) /
                            _tireDiameter;
                      } else if (j == 5) {
                        value1 = (_finalDrive *
                                (i * 10 * mphtokmph) *
                                _gear6 *
                                _coefficient) /
                            _tireDiameter;
                      }
                      values[int.parse(((j) * (i)).toStringAsFixed(0))] =
                          value1;
                    }
                  }
              });
            },
```

output comes out like this:
`I/flutter (21824): [47049.25, 1383.39, 2766.77, 4150.16, 5533.55, 6916.93, 8300.32, 9683.7, 11067.09, 12450.48, 13833.86, 15217.25, 16600.64, 17984.02, 19367.41, 20750.8, 22134.18, 23517.57, 24900.96, 26284.34, 27667.73, 4940.67, 10504.56, null, 11459.52, 2075.08, 12414.48, 6352.28, 13369.44, null, 14324.4, null, 15279.36, 7763.9, 16234.32, 2905.11, 17189.28, null, 18144.24, 9175.52, 19099.2, null, 9881.33, null, 5652.12, 10587.14, null, null, 11292.95, null, 4150.16, 11998.76, 6679.78, null, 12704.57, 4565.18, 7193.61, 13410.38, null, null, 14116.19, null, null, null, 8221.27, 5395.21, 4565.18, null, 8735.1, null, 5810.22, null, 9248.93, null, null, 6225.24, 9762.76, null, 5395.21, null, 10276.58, null, null, null, 5810.22, 7055.27, null, null, null, null, 7470.29, null, null, null, null, 7885.3, 6640.25, null, null, null, 8300.32, null, 7055.27, null, null, null, null, null, 7470.29, null, null, null, null, null, 7885.3, null, null, null, null, null]`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it's code-smell when you have named variables with suffixed numbers.  This code would be far simpler if you had `gear[j]` instead of separate variables.  You wouldn't even need the inner switch, just `var value= (_finalDrive * (i * 10 * mphtokmph) * gear[j] * _coefficient) / _tireDiameter;`  See, much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the index of array
the code

```
indice = -1 
For loop1...
  For loop2...
   indice = indice +1 
      :
      :
value[indice] = value1
```

Comment: All variables are double and even the values that are not null are wrong somehow, i used the same equation in excel and got 908.3 for the first value

Comment: if it helps the value of _finalDrive is 4.11, mphtokmph is 1.609344, _coefficient is 336.13, _tireDiameter is 31.5, _gear1 is 3.333, _gear2 is 1.96, _gear3 is 1.353, _gear4 is 1, _gear5 is 0.728 and _gear6 is 0.588

Comment: i dont know well dart, but you put the result in array, so the value of each element in index  i * j , is it normal? each time j = 0, you write in index 0..  The first index is 0 and the last is 5 * 19

Comment: Oh okay i get what you mean, that makes sense but how should i make it so it goes from element 0 to 119 inside the for loop

Comment: I think i figured it out, I'll have a separate counter in the inner loop that increments everytime and I'll use that as the index for the list, thanks

Comment: you just add a new value indice intialized before loop at -1 and you just do indice = indice + 1. jsute after the beginning of second loop.. and then value[indice] = value1.. its the easier